# installing Ninite application with powershell on remote servers.

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, virtual

I am trying to install .net4.6.2 on to a remote server using a powershell script. I downloaded the file locally onto my machine and then I use the powershell script to copy the file from local machine to the Virtual machine and install the software, however it fails or disappear from the task manager half way through.The copying works fine. The part that I am having issue with is actually starting and completing the process. 
The script below is the one I am using:

```
#Variables
$computername = Get-Content C:\PSdeploy\list.txt
$sourcefile = "C:\temp\NET462.exe"
#This section will install the software 
foreach ($computer in $computername) 
{
    $destinationFolder = "\\$computer\C$\Temp"
    #This section will copy the $sourcefile to the $destinationfolder. If the Folder does not exist it will create it.
    if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationFolder))
    {
        New-Item $destinationFolder -Type Directory
    }
    Copy-Item -Path $sourcefile -Destination $destinationFolder
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {Start-Process -FilePath "C:\temp\NET462.exe"  -Wait -Verb RunAs -PassThr}
}


Read-Host
```

Comment: whats the error? also, why don't you want to start the process from a remote share, that way you don't have to copy the same file over and over? Also, is there a typo in the end? `PassThr`

Comment: I am not seeing an error, but I do watch the task the from  task manager so I know it was downloading the file, but i believe its failing at the install process.

Comment: My apologies yes there was a typo at the "passthru" command.

Comment: well, I'm pretty sure you need at least some sort of `quiet` switch